# Convert BDS function with end date override to get index historical composition in Python?

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am having an issue with the BDS function. It's a function that returns data from Bloomberg in bulk. However, this function in excel also has the ability to return bulk data for a ticker at a certain date, like this.

```
=BDS("SX5E Index", "INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST", "END_DATE_OVERRIDE", "20220708")
```

The issue I have with this function in Python is that while it has to pulled by a "ReferenceData" request, there's only the "endDate" input for "HistoricalData" requests. I have tried overriding the request by adding either "END_DT" or "endDate" etc but I receive an error basically saying that "ReferenceData" request does not have these Sub-elements. I have looked for blpapi wrappers online but can't seem to find a solution to this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. Have you tried with `INDX_MWEIGHT_PX` (just looking at some of my code and seeing that field used)? 2. The Bloomberg API allows adding overrides to ReferenceData requests - it may be a limitation of the Python library you are using. 3. In the case of `INDX_MWEIGHT_PX` the override is `END_DATE_OVERRIDE`.

Comment: 1. It's more like an issue with building the request, I tried "END_DT" and "endDate" as elements for the request but it shows error. 2. I use blpapi, do you know if Bloomberg has a guide with all the possible override parameters to their ReferenceData request?

Comment: 1. Probably a limitation of the Python library - maybe try another one? I know for a fact that the underlying API allows overrides using the Java API. 2. The best way is to enter `SX5E Index FLDS MWEIGHT <Go>` on a terminal - that will show a list of available fields containing "MWEIGHT". Click on `INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST` and you will see a list of overrides.

Comment: FWIW ... that Excel function doesn't return any weights. You get the members, but no weights. Also if I look at `SX5E Index FLDS Go` in the Terminal, there is no bulk data either for the current value (INDX_MWEIGHT), except for the members. I suggest you contact the Help Desk to ask why the weights are `N.A.`. This may be one of the things that they have migrated over to BQL (and hence are no longer available via the DAPI).